# Xamarin cannot connect to Mac from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

When I try to use iPhone simulator, I get an error that VS2017 cannot connect to MAC. 
[image: Cannot connect from VS2017]
Configuration and software:

- Visual Studio 2017 15.2 (26430.14)
- Mac OS Sierra 10.12
- Latest XCode installed on Mac and the licence is accepted
- On Mac, remote login is enabled
- Firewall is  disabled on Mac
- In VS when I try to connect to Mac,  I can see the MacBook but I just can't  connect using  username and password I use for login to Mac

I am  however  able  to  connect using ssh:

[image: Connection via ssh and putty]

Comment: can you ssh to the mac using command prompt in windows? You can check the command in remote login settings in mac. Something like "ssh [username]@[ip address]"

Comment: there's a "connection timeout" when I try to connect via putty and ssh

Comment: I tried again.. I can successfully connect via putty and ssh

Comment: You can try to check in the logs file to see what is the error. The log files can be found in Mac – ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin-[MAJOR.MINOR], 
Windows – %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs

Comment: I am having the exact same difficulty and I too can login with no problem via SSH.

Comment: I figured out..on Mac I had to install the latest xamarin studio with xamarin.ios sdk. The versions must match.

Comment: I am facing the same issue . now. i have Xamarn Studio in Mac. How do i compare both Mac and Windows has the same Xamarin.ios.sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I suggest that:
Xamarin studio should be installed 
Xamarin.iOS SDK should be installed
You should be logged in with that account on your mac.

```
A Mac running OS X El Capitan (10.11) or higher (although the latest stable version is recommended).
Xamarin Studio 5.10 or higher (although the latest stable version is recommended)). This should be on the same distribution channel as Xamarin for Visual Studio.
Xamarin.iOS SDK.
Apple’s Xcode(7+) IDE and iOS SDK (although the latest stable version from the App Store is recommended)).
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: Why can't I use Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: you can. but for that you also need to install xamarin studio on mac

Comment: I tried installing Visual Studio Xamarin on my Mac.  It finally finished installing on the Mac and then when I went to Visual Studio 2017 and tried to connect, it _did_ indeed actually work.  That is actually quite terrible because it is not intuitive nor obvious that you have to install VStudio on the Mac also.  Well, at least it works now.  Thanks